# android replace multiple characters from a string

Tags: java, android

I know that this may be an amateur question but for some reason I can't remember how to do this.
I have 2 strings.

```
String s ="[";
String q ="]";
```

if my text contains any of these i want to replace it with `w` which is:

```
String w = "";
```

I have tried the following:

```
output=String.valueOf(profile.get("text")).replace(s&&q, w);
```

from what i understand if of S([) and any of Q(]) are in text they will be replaced with w.
my problem is getting the 2. if i only try and replace one then it will work. otherwise it wont.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can nest them up too:

```
 output=String.valueOf(profile.get("text")).replace(s, w).replace(q, w);
```

Comment: that's doing the same as before. just replacing s and not replacing the q

Comment: have you changed it? it looks the same

Comment: Yep, I've removed this line from it - **String.valueOf(profile.get("text"))**

Comment: hmmm. i need that bit lol. thats where i'm getting my text from, from my json feed

Comment: i do apologise. your first attempt worked. i was inserting it into the wrong place :S
thanks for your help

Comment: i'm having one of them days where my brain says nah i'm staying in bed

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9631/discussion-between-creator-and-tuffy-g)

Answer (score 11):

I think this is what you mean:

```
String s = "abc[def]";
String w = "hello";

System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", w));
```

Outputs `abchellodefhello`.

`String.replaceAll()` accepts a regular expression as its first argument, which would provide the flexibility required.

Comment: it makes sence however the ] is not removed

Comment: Did you copy the posted code or did you edit new source? I have just reran this and it definitely replaces both the `[` and the `]`. The `[` and `]` must be escaped as they are special characters in regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "[";
String q = "]";
String w = "{";
String as = "sdada[sad]sdas";
String newstring = as.replace(s, w).replace(q,w);
Toast.makeText(_activity,newstring,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is the working code for you...

Answer (score 1):

If you read on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29 you will see that it takes two char objects as an argument. The construction "s && q" and "s || q" are both illegal and gibberish. Think of it: what exactly would the logical operation ("foo" && "bar") return?

Do this:

```
output = String.valueOf(profile.get("text")).replace(q, w).replace(s, w);
```

This will yield what you want.

Comment: i understand. the && was a last resort thing after i tried out a millionm and one other ways around

Answer (score 0):

check out this

```
String s ="[";
    String q ="]";
    String w = "";

    String output=w.replace("[", w);
    output=output.replace("]", w);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution in 2022, just do the following.

```
    String s = "[";
    String q = "]";
    String w = "";
    String text = Some[ Text ] here;
    
    text = text.replace(s, w );
    text = text.replace(q, w );
    String output = text;
```

Answer (score -1):

try using [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method from java.lang.String.